# How to show field values in Julia

Tags: oop, field, julia

I was wondering if there is a possibility to show field values in Julia.

For example, this Python program, gets the object variable `wealth` from the consumer class:

```
   class Consumer:

    def __init__(self, w):
        "Initialize consumer with w dollars of wealth"
        self.wealth = w

    def earn(self, y):
        "The consumer earns y dollars"
        self.wealth += y

    def spend(self, x):
        "The consumer spends x dollars if feasible"
        new_wealth = self.wealth - x
        if new_wealth < 0:
            print("Insufficent funds")
        else:
            self.wealth = new_wealth

c1.wealthc1 = Consumer(10) # Create instance with initial wealth 10
c1.spend(5)
c1.wealth
```

The wealth variable is `5`. I want to know how can I translate this code to Julia.

Comment: Could you change you wording to something different than "show"? At first reading, I thought your problem was how to _print_ data types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest approach is pretty much like Python:

```
mutable struct Consumer
    wealth
end

function earn(c::Consumer, y)
    c.wealth += y
end

function spend(c::Consumer, y)
    c.wealth -= y
end
```

And now you can use it like:

```
julia> c1 = Consumer(10)
Consumer(10)

julia> spend(c1, 5)
5

julia> c1.wealth
5
```

You can read more about it [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/types/#man-types-1).

But probably in Julia you would write it like:

```
mutable struct ConsumerTyped{T<:Real}
    wealth::T
end

function earn(c::ConsumerTyped, y)
    c.wealth += y
end

function spend(c::ConsumerTyped, y)
    c.wealth -= y
end
```

Which on surface will work almost the same. The difference is `T` which specifies the type of `wealth`. There are two benefits: you get type control in your code and the functions will run faster.

Given such a definition the only thing you need to know is that the constructor can be called in two flavors:

```
c2 = ConsumerTyped{Float64}(10) # explicitly specifies T
c3 = ConsumerTyped(10) # T implicitly derived from the argument
```

Now let us compare the performance of both types:

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> c1 = Consumer(10)
Consumer(10)

julia> c2 = ConsumerTyped(10)
ConsumerTyped{Int64}(10)

julia> @benchmark spend(c1, 1)
BenchmarkTools.Trial:
  memory estimate:  16 bytes
  allocs estimate:  1
  --------------
  minimum time:     56.434 ns (0.00% GC)
  median time:      57.376 ns (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        60.126 ns (0.84% GC)
  maximum time:     847.942 ns (87.69% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          10000
  evals/sample:     992

julia> @benchmark spend(c2, 1)
BenchmarkTools.Trial:
  memory estimate:  16 bytes
  allocs estimate:  1
  --------------
  minimum time:     29.858 ns (0.00% GC)
  median time:      30.791 ns (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        32.835 ns (1.63% GC)
  maximum time:     966.188 ns (90.20% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          10000
  evals/sample:     1000
```

and you see that you get ~2x speedup.

Comment: As Daniel Muhlbachler points out - this is not exactly OOP but you get what you want with multiple dispatch. There key real difference between Julia and OOP in Python is that only abstract types can have subtypes in Julia as explained here https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/types/ so you have to use composition instead of inheritance in some situations https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance.

Comment: Since you are mutating the objects, the functions should be called `earn!` and `spend!`. On the other hand it might be better (faster) to use a non-mutable `struct`.

Answer (score 3):

Julia **doesn't support** classes (in terms of OOP).

However, there are [**composite types**](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/types/#Composite-Types-1) which can represent the variables of your class:

```
type Consumer
    wealth::Float64
end
```

Now, since Julia doesn't support classes, all methods have to live outside this type which allows one of the key features of Julia, *multiple dispatch*, to also work with user-defined types. (https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/methods/, https://www.juliabloggers.com/julia-in-ecology-why-multiple-dispatch-is-good/)
Hence, you would have to add a method like this:

```
function earn!(consumer::Consumer, y::Float64)
    println("The consumer earns y dollars")
    consumer.wealth = consumer.wealth + y
end
```

(Similarly, the `spend` function can be implemented.)

Comment: Agreed. A small comment is that `type` keyword is currently replaced by `mutable struct` keyword (and if you would write `struct` the type would be immutable).